# I need to use Overflow-Y as visible and Overflow-X as scroll at the same time, but it doesnt work

Tags: html, css, overflow

Ok, someone here insisted in adding a form inside a table line (i told it wasnt a good idea) now we're having problems with the ng-select (select with search) and the responsive table. I need the table to activate scroll when overflows horizontally (blue arrow), but i also need that vertically overflows (red arrow) stay visible (don't scroll).

The problem is that when i add overflow-x auto or scroll or anything that isnt visible, the dropdown select just breaks. I've tried adding overflow-y: visible, but it appears that the dropdown select only listens to the overflow-x property.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaWV6.png)

(I don't know if you guys noticed, but in image 1, the select dropdown is cutted)

Also, if i add overflow-x: visible to the parent div, it breaks the responsive table. (Image 2)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJvBg.png)

I think i've tried everything, can someone please help?

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to better help you, would you please update your question to contain all relevant code in a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, providing screenshots of the problem and details of what you’ve tried, make it much more likely that you’ll get a useful answer. 

For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: Yup, you can't combine overflow-x:visible with any overflow-y value other than visible, and vice-versa